# how can i update a python file by comparing it to a file hosted on my rasbery pi?

Tags: python, auto-update

I am attempting to make a program update itself to the newest version that I have made. E.g. I added a new functionality to it. It would be useful for me to be able to upload the updated file to a central location like my Raspberry Pi and have the program update itself across all of my computers without updating each one individually.

I have made the bellow code, but it does not work. It can recognize when the file is up-to-date but running the new program it downloads fails, it successfully downloads and deletes itself, but the new program is not run, with no error messages being shown.

Update test.py:

```
#updaterV1.py
import time
import requests
import os
import hashlib
time.sleep(5)
cwd = os.getcwd()
URL = r"http://[rasberry pi's ip]/update%20files/dev/hash.txt"
hash_path = os.path.join(cwd,"remote hash.txt")

with open (hash_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(URL).content)

with open(hash_path,"r") as hash_file:
    remotehash = (hash_file.readline()).strip()
os.remove(hash_path)

hasher = hashlib.sha256()
with open(__file__, 'rb') as self_file:
    selfunhashed = self_file.read()

hasher.update(selfunhashed)
selfhash = hasher.hexdigest()

print(selfhash)
print(remotehash)

if (selfhash == remotehash):
    print("program is up to date")
    input()
else:
    update_path =  os.path.join(cwd,"temp name update.py") 
    URL = r"http://[rasberry pi's ip]/update%20files/dev/update.py" 


    with open (update_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(URL).content)

    with open(update_path,"r") as f:
        name = f.readline().strip() 
        name = name[1:] #use the 1st line as "#name.py" not "# name"
    update_path = os.path.join(cwd,name)
    try:
        os.remove(update_path)
    except:
        pass
    os.rename(os.path.join(cwd,"temp name update.py"),update_path)
    os.system("python \""+update_path+"\"") 
    print("removing self file now")
    os.remove(__file__)
```

It uses a separate TXT file with the hash of the program stored in the same folder to check the remote files hash without downloading the actual file to hash it locally.

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error message? Does it do the wrong thing? Exactly which operation (download, rename, or run) fails?

Comment: @larsks running the new program fails, it successfully downloads and deletes itself, but the new program is not run, with no error messages being shown.

Comment: Imagine you had a `hello.py` that greets the world. Are you convinced the os.system call above would successfully display Hello World ? (I'm trying to make this independent of any downloading details, including `chmod a+x *.py` and including the odd `r` / `rb` / `w` / `wb` mixture of text & binary we see above.)